Local SQL Server -> MS Managed SQL warehouse via ADF. Compare UniqueID column in both to delete/insert the changes?
I have a local SQL server that is maintaining a replica of our ERP production db. I use SQLAgent to run SSIS packages that truncate the replica and do a full copy of the prod db. I am adding a uniqueID column that is a hashbyte of all columns after casting to varchar and concatenating.
I want to use this uniqueID to find rows in our company's cloud warehouse that need to be deleted or added. I have tried pulling them into a dataflow as sources, but dataflow doesn't work with SHIR sources. So I did a copy tool to Azure blob csv that just captures this uniqueID column, then open this csv in dataflow. When I try joining the two csv files in dataflow it seems like the hashes (now strings, because csv) aren't lining up. Even if the join did seem to work, it still feels very inefficient to save the column to blob storage before processing.
Is there a better way to do this in a pipeline?

Step 1: Setup Staging Tables
In your Azure SQL Data Warehouse, create staging tables to temporarily hold data from the local SQL Server.
CREATE TABLE StagingTable (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    UniqueID VARBINARY(64) -- Ensure this matches your hash function output
);

Step 2: Copy Data from Local SQL Server
Use a Copy Data Activity in ADF to copy data from the local SQL Server to the staging table.
Source: Local SQL Server
Sink: Azure SQL Data Warehouse staging table
Step 3: Compare Data in the Warehouse
Use a stored procedure or SQL script to identify differences.
-- Deleted Rows
SELECT ID
INTO #ToDelete
FROM WarehouseTable
WHERE UniqueID NOT IN (SELECT UniqueID FROM StagingTable);

-- Inserted/Updated Rows
SELECT ID, UniqueID
INTO #ToInsertOrUpdate
FROM StagingTable
WHERE UniqueID NOT IN (SELECT UniqueID FROM WarehouseTable);

Step 4: Apply Changes
Use a stored procedure or ADF Stored Procedure Activity to apply the changes.
-- Delete outdated rows
DELETE FROM WarehouseTable
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM #ToDelete);

-- Insert or update rows
MERGE INTO WarehouseTable AS Target
USING StagingTable AS Source
ON Target.ID = Source.ID
WHEN MATCHED AND Target.UniqueID <> Source.UniqueID THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.UniqueID = Source.UniqueID, -- Update other fields as needed
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ID, UniqueID) VALUES (Source.ID, Source.UniqueID);

